# How to fix Error: SSL connect error when connecting to aws ec2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just created an EC2 instance for my web server and I run into this whenever i try connecting to it:

This site can’t provide a secure connection
18.170.25.198 sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just connect on http, it works for me
http://18.170.25.198:8001/api